# Have twitter bootstrap modal scale?

Tags: css, twitter, modal-dialog

I am using a "high" modal from twitter bootsrap. Is it possible to have it scale with lower resolutions? If I choose a lower resolution I can't see the whole modal. I would like it to fit on the screen no matter what. If it does not fit I would like it to be scrollable(that actualy happens sometimes /max-height: 400px). Is the only thing I can do adjust the max height?

```
.modal-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 750px;
  margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: I would like the background to be scrollable like the last ont in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HGDe5pdAw0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.modal {
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: Answers with only code and no explanation are less helpful. Even if you just explain what the code does, it makes it a lot clearer, and it shows your knowledge if you can say *why* something works, not just what works.

On the other hand, this code works, and it's not a complex question. So in this case, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although the proposed solution works, when you use **position: absolute**, if the scrollbar of the window is lower than that (ie. top is out of sight), the modal shows itself and then the scrollbar 'jumps' to the top of it.

Another option is to adjust the height of the modal depending the height of the window. To do that, just add the following rules:

```
/* Since the position of the modal is top: 10%, this rules guarantees that its
centered vertically */
div.modal.fade.in { height: 80%; }

/* This rule shows the footer at the bottom of the modal and sets its width
so it looks good */
div.modal div.modal-footer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 94%;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* Finally, we set the bottom of the body so its above the footer 
and its top so its bellow the header of the modal */
div.modal div.modal-body{
    position: absolute;
    width: 94%;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 60px;
}
```

Hope it helps